# I am trying to Read, write and translate of the bmp image file using c/c++, the output bmp file format not supported on window (using visual studio)

Tags: c, visual-studio-2010, image-processing, visual-c++, bmp

**Code starts form here**

```
//creat the stucture for the bitmap file, which consist the header of size 54, which contains the information about the file.     
    struct BMP {
        int width;
        int height;
        unsigned char header[54];
        unsigned char *pixels;
        int size;
    };
```

Read and write function for the bmp file in c/c++.
Here I used the fopen() function

```
// read the image
BMP readBMP(string filename) {
    BMP image;
    int i;
    string fileName = filename;
    FILE *f = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "rb");
    fread(image.header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, f); // read the 54-byte header

    // extract image height and width from header
    image.width = *(int *) &image.header[18];
    image.height = *(int *) &image.header[22];
    cout<<"inage width: "<< image.width <<", image height: "<< image.height <<endl;

    image.size = 3 * image.width * image.height;
    image.pixels = new unsigned char[image.size]; // allocate 3 bytes per pixel
    fread(image.pixels, sizeof(unsigned char), image.size, f); // read the rest of the data at once
    fclose(f);

    // bmp stors data in BGR format, so changing the BGR to RGB.
    for (i = 0; i < image.size; i += 3) {
        unsigned char tmp = image.pixels[i];
        image.pixels[i] = image.pixels[i + 2];
        image.pixels[i + 2] = tmp;
    }
    return image;
}

// write image
void writeBMP(string filename, BMP image) {
    string fileName = filename;
    FILE *out = fopen(fileName.c_str(), "wb");
    fwrite(image.header, sizeof(unsigned char), 54, out);
    int i;
    unsigned char tmp;
    for (i = 0; i < image.size; i += 3) {
        tmp = image.pixels[i];
        image.pixels[i] = image.pixels[i + 2];
        image.pixels[i + 2] = tmp;
    }
    fwrite(image.pixels, sizeof(unsigned char), image.size, out); // read the rest of the data at once
    fclose(out);
}
```

Image translating function, to translate image corresponding x and y dimension.

```
// image translation
BMP translation(BMP image, int tx, int ty) {
    BMP newImage = image;
    unsigned char *pixel = new unsigned char[image.size];

    // translation
    for (int x = 0; x < image.width; ++x){
        for (int y = 0; y < image.height; ++y) {
            int xx = x-tx;
            int yy = y+ty;
            if (xx >= 0 && xx < image.width && yy >= 0 && yy < image.height){
                pixel[(y * image.width + x) * 3 + 0] = image.pixels[(yy * image.width + xx) * 3 + 0];
                pixel[(y * image.width + x) * 3 + 1] = image.pixels[(yy * image.width + xx) * 3 + 1];
                pixel[(y * image.width + x) * 3 + 2] = image.pixels[(yy * image.width + xx) * 3 + 2];
            }
        }
    }
    newImage.pixels = pixel;
    return newImage;
}
```

main function call to perform the read, write and translate operation, is below.

```
int main() {
    BMP image = readBMP("sample_640×426.bmp"); 
    BMP image_t;

    // // original image
    writeBMP("Output-11.bmp", image);

    // image translation
    int x0=100, y0=50;
    image_t = translation(image, x0, y0);
    writeBMP("Out_translate.bmp", image_t);

    return 0;
}
```

windows output image is here[1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/gd83D.png

Comment: Please provide complete code as a [mre]. For example, it is not clear how these functions are being called and what the exact input is.

Comment: @kaylum I have include the main function, where I called these functions.

Comment: what's the dimensions of your image (width/height)?

Comment: `image.size = 3 * image.width * image.height;` First. how sure are you that the BMP is in 24bpp format? You are not checking `BITMAPINFOHEADER::biBitCount`. Second, even with 24bpp format, each scan line is padded to a 4-byte boundary, so the total data size is larger than `3*width*height` whenever `width` is not a multiple of 4.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik could you please share, how can I add the padding to the code. because I do not know about it.

Comment: @YakovGalka width 640 & height 426

Comment: What's the size in bytes of the original file, `sample_640×426.bmp`?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Image width is 640 and height is 426

Comment: I asked about the size of the file in bytes, not of the bitmap in pixels. The latter you already mentioned in a previous comment.

Comment: Sorry @IgorTandetnik I got it wrong. The byte size of image file is 8,80,58 bytes and output file is 8,17,974 bytes.

Comment: Then it can't possibly be a 24bpp bitmap as you assume. The size of the image file is about one tenth of what it would have to be if that were true (or else you made a typo in your comment, and the size is not in fact eighty eight thousand fifty eight).

Comment: Ohh sorry, @IgorTandetnik I made a typo mistake while commenting. The input image file size is 8,18,058 bytes.